# Wrong Content-Type in response in IErrorHandler

Tags: rest, error-handling, biztalk

I would like to send response to my service in JSON format. I catch my custom errors in my custom behavior:

```
void IErrorHandler.ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)

        {

            XDocument errorMsg = XDocument.Parse("<errorMessage>" + error.Message + "</errorMessage>");

            var jsonWriter = new JsonErrorBodyWriter(errorMsg);

            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, null, jsonWriter);

            fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));

            HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();

            prop.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

            prop.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");  

            prop.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
            --Tried different ways to achieve this



            fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);

        }
```

But I get wrong content-type in response. And also I couldn't manage to write any custom header like :

```
prop.Headers.Add("Test", "Value");
```

Reponse:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2020 08:41:15 GMT

Content-Length: 37


{"description":"Autorization Failed"}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you sending the error to the caller of the service or are you consuming a service and throwing an error back to BizTalk?  Have you debug stepped through your code when it executes?

Comment: Im sending it back to the caller.  Should I handle it in orchestration? No I haven't debug because I while attach my debugger to iis w3wp process or host process- it doesn't stop/break.